# Convert single branch history into many smaller merged branches

Tags: git, rebase

**Problem**

Basically, I have a bad habit of forgetting to make branches during development. This leaves me with a massive trail of commits, that's hard to see where one feature begins and the next finishes.

**Possible Solution**

The commits are in order I just want to be able to break the single master branch into several smaller feature branches that merge back into the master.

Current Git Repo:

```
-- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H => master
```

Ideal Git Repo:

```
       B -- C => feature1 
     /       \
-- A --------- D -- E --------- H => master
                     \        /    
                       F -- G => feature2
```

**What I've Tried**

I've read some other similar questions, but couldn't find any describing my problem. I've tried `git rebase` but am not really sure exactly how to use it in this situation, also it might need the `--onto` option apparently.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as this will make my repositories a lot nicer to look at!

Comment: I think what you want will make your history much uglier to look at.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: In the example you will have to explicitly ask git to make merge commits when a fast-forward would do. If you let git perform a fast forward, you're back to the linear history. Can you please explain which problem you're trying to solve here? Ideally, as time go on, you'd delete both `feature1` and `feature2` branches, why do consider the second example more ideal than the first?

Comment: If you want to stop the merges from fast-forwarding you can use the `--no-ff` flag. This will create merge commits even when a fast-forward is available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**LEGEND**

- `A'` means patch and message from commit `A`, but a different commit hash, because the parent has changed.
- `branch-name*` means `branch-name` is the currently checkout branch as `HEAD`

---

```
-- A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H => master


       B -- C -- D
     /            \
-- A ------------- M1 -- E ------------ M2 => master
                          \            /    
                            F -- G -- H
```

> Note that in your diagram you have marked having your previous non-merge commits `D` and `H` as merge commits in the end. I don't believe this is what you want as you would usually have different patches and messages in these commits which you want to keep separate from the merge commit. I've added `M1` and `M2` respectively in the end result.

You should be able to use this:

`git checkout master`

`git reset --hard A`

```
-- A => master*
    \
      B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H
```

`git checkout -b feature1 D` (not needed, but could act as a label)

```
                   => feature1
                 /                       
      B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H
     /
-- A => master*
```

`git merge --no-ff feature1`

```
                   => feature1
                 /                       
       B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H
     /            \
-- A ------------- M1 => master*
```

`git cherry-pick E`

```
                     => feature1
                   /                       
       B -- C --  D -- E -- F -- G -- H
     /             \
-- A -------------- M1 -- E' => master*
```

`git checkout -b feature2 H`

```
                     => feature1
                   /                       
       B -- C --  D -- E -- F -- G -- H => feature2*
     /             \
-- A -------------- M1 -- E' => master
```

`git rebase --onto E master`

> Reset to master, cherry pick everything from `E` to `H` on top with rebase.

---

> Note we choose `E` here and not `E'` as `--onto` is about the history of the branch being rebased, not what we are rebasing *on top of*. Equivalent would be `git rebase --onto F^ master` where `F^` means the parent of `F` in Git.

```
                     => feature1
                   /                       
       B -- C --  D -- E -- F -- G -- H
     /             \
-- A -------------- M1 -- E' => master
                            \
                             F' -- G' -- H' => feature2*
```

`git checkout master`

```
                     => feature1
                   /                       
       B -- C --  D -- E -- F -- G -- H
     /             \
-- A -------------- M1 -- E' => master*
                            \
                             F' -- G' -- H' => feature2
```

`git merge --no-ff feature2`

```
                   => feature1
                 /                       
      B -- C -- D -- E -- F -- G -- H
     /           \
-- A ------------ M1 -- E' --------------- M2 => master*
                          \               /    
                            F' -- G' -- H' => feature2
```

Final result when commits without any named ref pointing to them are discarded:

```
      B -- C -- D => feature1
     /           \
-- A ------------ M1 -- E' --------------- M2 => master*
                          \               /    
                            F' -- G' -- H' => feature2
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to be more complete and accurate and explained more the `rebase --onto` step.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably follow this pattern:

```
git checkout -b master_backup master
```

Then

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard [SHA position]
```

Note SHA position is just the commit hash you'd like to begin with.

Now

```
git checkout -b feature-name master
git cherry-pick [sha-1]^...[sha-2]
```

Note, the `^` symbol makes the cherry pick range inclusive of [sha-1]

Then finally

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature
```

And continue the final 4 steps for every feature you'd like to add to your master topology

Answer (score 0):

The "ideal" graph is a bit ambiguous because the merge commits are not specified clearly. In the graph, `D` and `H` seem to be merge commits, but they should not be.

Here's one possible solution to rebuild a history graph:

```
git checkout master
git reset A --hard
git cherry-pick D
git branch feature1 C
git merge feature1 --no-ff
git cherry-pick E
git branch feature2
git cherry-pick H
git checkout feature2
git cherry-pick F G
git checkout master
git merge feature2 --no-ff
```

Note that `feature1` and `feature2` are local branches so far. You could push them to the remote if necessary. Besieds, `master` has been rewritten. You may need to force-push it to update it in the remote repository.